# How to control color theme using configurations in Django admin?

Tags: css, django, docker, sass

Basically I have Django project (using Docker) installed on many sites with different logos, content, etc. Problem seems to be that also theme colors should be configurable for each site. Optimal solution would be to have some color codes (primary, secondary, etc) configurable, which would eventually change CSS content. Project uses Bootstrap 4, which uses SASS (SCSS) that compiles as CSS, so now my GIT contains single SCSS file and compiled final CSS should be different on each site.

All solutions I have figured out seem to be hacks, so I wonder is there any "clean solutions" for this? Solution don't have to be necessarily "real time", like configurations in Django Admin UI, but that would definitely be plus. Anyway, something that works even if I make changes to common code base and update that to all sites.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030098/customize-css-from-code-django#28030224 ?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem in elegant way, more like a hack. That does not use styles.scss (css) at all and therefore having for example common button style would cause huge amount of code all around HTML.